# Always null recurrence at the boundary between positive recurrence and transience?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

I have the following theorem:

> Let $\rho$ be the traffic intensity.
>
> a) If  $\rho<1$, then $X$ is positive recurrent.
>
> b) If $\rho>1$, then $X$ is transient.
>
> c) If $\rho=1$, then $X$ is null-reсurrent.

It is not important what exactly $\rho$ and $X$ are. Let's assume I have proved a) and b). Then it remains to prove the case $\rho=1$:

Can I say the following: $X$ is transient if and only if $\rho>1$, and is positive recurrent if and only if $\rho<1$. If $\rho=1$ then $X$ has no choice but null-recurrent.

Is that correct?

Comment: Can you think of a better title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) If  $\rho<1$, then $X$ is positive recurrent.
>
> Let's assume I have proved a)
>
> Can I say the following: $X$ is positive recurrent if and only if $\rho<1$

No, you cannot - you have only proved that $\rho <1$ is a sufficient condition for the positive recurrence of $X$, but you have not established its necessity. So you can say, $X$ is positive recurrent if $\rho<1$, but you can't use *if and only if*.

Let us say, in one universe there are boys, girls and wardrobes, and only three names are used: John, Jane and Woody. After spending some time there, you mention that John is only used for boys and Jane is only used for girls. You still can't conclude the Woody is only used for wardrobes, as there may happen to be a boy called Woody.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that correct?

No, first because there is no proof here, second because in some settings the boundary case is positive recurrent, respectively transient.

Comment: As the OP wrote, it does not matter what are $\rho$ and $X$, and the question is whether the way he proves c) from a) and b) is correct. Hence, the question is more about logic than about Markov chains (and the title better reflect that). Unless you have any objections, I'll do retitling and retagging again.

Comment: @Ilya It seems your comment is addressed to the OP. As such, its natural place is as a comment to the question, not to my answer--or am I missing something?

Comment: Since you've overwritten my first edit of the OP (where I put the tag "logic" and changed the title), I thought before doing the second edit of the same kind I'd ask whether you're ok with that.

Comment: @Ilya Ah OK, I had not this in mind. Well, this is as much (logic) as virtually any question on the site hence no, no tag (logic).